# i want to retrieve location from promise aaray of open cage geocoding by passing lat and log but dont know how to retrieve the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

i want to retrieve the location from the fetched API of open cage geocoding which has the following structure
[this picture contains the structure of data strogae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqyKi.png)

pls help me out

Comment: How are you fetching the data? Fetch? Axios?

Comment: fetch(`https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${Latitude}+${Longitude}&key=############################`) @Patric

Answer (score 0):

When using fetch you can usually accomplish it like this:

```
fetch("https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=51+16&key=YOUR_KEY")
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then( data => console.log(data.results))
```

The first line returns a response Promise. The second line contains instructions on how to parse the response body. In this case, you want to parse JSON, hence, you call res.json().
More on the latter part can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Body).